# How can I find intersections of three hexagons on this figure?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, graph-algorithm

I have a figure looks like this
[image]
I want to find the coordinates of all intersections of three hexagons.

How can I do this? Should I use OpenCV?

Comment: Are you obliged to use shabby (lossy) JPEG - it is often a poor format for storing intermediate results in image processing? Can you use PNG?

Comment: What about the pentagon at around `[1100,300]`?

Comment: @ Mark Setchell No, this is only a snapshot of the figure, I can save the figure in PNG format. Yes, in fact, I want to find all intersections in this figure, I don't know whether there is a way to do it, I'm satisfied if the intersections of hexagons are found.

Comment: How are you getting on - any progress? You've gone very quiet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still trying to think of a faster/better method, but I think the following should work:

- threshold your image to pure blacks and whites
- generate and save a list of all black pixels for later
- label your image so that each white hexagon is effectively flood-filled with a unique color (or shade of grey) - some folks call this *"labelling"*, some call it *"Blob Analysis"*, some call it *"Connected Component Analysis"*. Whatever it is called, you will get something like this:

[image]

- Now look at each black pixel from the list you saved in the second step and count how many different colours other than black are in the surrounding 9x9, or 15x15 area. If it's three it is probably an intersection like you are looking for.

Of course there are variations on this - you could implement a *"minimum distance from other intersection"* on top, for example. Or a *"black line thinning first"*. Or a dilation of each blob to erode the black lines and make the three colours closer together. You could scale your image down (being careful to use NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR rather than interpolation) after labelling to reduce processing time - if important.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find these features using [Harris corner detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html).

Also check if  `findContours` with analysis of result intersections could give you useful information.